# Regex IP for URL problem

Tags: regex

```
const string strRegex = @"^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}"
   "(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]$";
Regex rgxUrl = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Compiled
   |RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If my URL is http://89.212.232.65 then this regex for checking URL fails. How must I change the regex so that will also work for IP addresses?

[I took editing liberties with the `strRegex` definition which is all one contiguous constant -msw]

Comment: There is probably a better way to accomplish what your are trying to do. What is your goal?

Comment: Which language is this for? (Add a tag)

Consider using a regexp library/module to match common (but easy to do wrong) patterns like ip/hostnames/urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const string strRegex = 
    @"^(http|https|ftp)\://" +
    @"(([a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})|([0-2]*\d*\d\.[0-2]*\d*\d\.[0-2]*\d*\d\.[0-2]*\d*\d))" +
    @"(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-._\?\,\'/\+&%\$#\=~])*[^.\,)(\s]$";
Regex rgxUrl = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

this one `.` in `+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}` doesn't make sense, you probably mean `\.`

This here works well for the first portion:

```
/^(https?|ftp):\/\/([-\w.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})|((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/
```

*(PCRE)*

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are doing some kind of validation? Or trying to extract host name? 
You don't need regex for this. Use Uri or UriBuilder classes